# iPad twitter interface in HTML5

Tags: ipad, html, twitter

Does anyone know a way of getting an HTML5 layout like the iPad application of Twitter? 
The iPad application of twitter is built as a native iOS app, but I was wondering whether something similar is possible using HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

There's no official things yet, but you can build your own using the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com), or the website. (I don't know whether it's iPad ready yet)

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use [jQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/) and/or [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) to create websites that look like iOS applications.